# Powershell: How to display all things / objects inside curly brackets?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, output

I would like to get/select all items inside the curly brackets. I've tried to select only the property and than select evything but it doesnt give the wanted result.

**Cmdlet**

`Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=test2OU,DC=corp-auryn,DC=serverlabs,DC=be" |select Propertynames |select *`

[image: Photo of Powershell cmdlet and output]

Comment: Change `Select PropertyName |Select *` to `Select -ExpandProperty PropertyNames`

Comment: As an aside: the `{...}` is the PowerShell's output formatting system's way of representing property values that are collections (arrays), which can be confusing, given that array literals in source code are created with `@(...)` or just `,`-separated elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has provided the crucial pointer:

In order to have [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) **extract only a property *value*** from its input objects, **that property's name must be passed to the `-ExpandProperty` parameter**.

- By default, with the (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter, even if you pass just *one* property name, that property's value is copied to a *property of the same name* in the output object, as evidenced by your output: a `[pscustomobject]` instance with a single property, `Propertynames`, was emitted.

Additionally, **if the property values happen to be *arrays*, their elements are *enumerated***.

- This enumeration does *not* happen with `-Property`.

---

Note that this means that when the name of an array-valued property is passed to `-ExpandProperty` and there are *multiple* input objects, a *flat* array of values is returned, which is the concatenation of the individual property-value arrays<sup>[1]</sup>, so that the input-object boundaries are lost:

A simple example:

```sh
[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1, 2 }, [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 3, 4 } |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty foo
```

The above outputs flat array `1, 2, 3, 4`.

---

Note that [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) behaves the same way - except that it requires the input collection to be collected in memory in full first:

```sh
# Except for not *streaming* the input objects, the result
# is the same as above:
([pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1, 2 }, [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 3, 4 }).foo
```

---

<sup>[1] Since the elements of a property that contains a *collection* - which or may not technically be an *array* - are *enumerated* to get the result, you'll always end up with regular PowerShell array, of type `[object[]]`.</sup>